# Best practices for asserting some condition in SQL when creating a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

Imagine I create some table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
...
```

Now I want to conduct some sanity check, verify some condition is true for every record of `mytable.` I could frame this problem as checking whether the result of another query returns zero results.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE something_horrible_is_true
```

Is there a standard, recommended way to generate an error here if the count is not equal to zero?  To make something happen such that if I'm executing this sanity check query using a `java.sql.Statement`, a SQLException is triggered?

Is this a reasonable approach? Or is this a better way to enforce that some condition is always true when creating a table? (I use Postgresql.)

Comment: Search for relational constraints, check constraints, not null constraint, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function to raise exception:

```
create or replace function raise_error(text) returns varchar as $body$
begin
  raise exception '%', $1;
  return null;
end; $body$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

Then you can use it in a regular SQLs:

```
SELECT case when count(*) > 0 then raise_error('something horrible is true!') end
FROM mytable
WHERE something_horrible_is_true
```

Here you will get the SQL exception if there are rows that satisfy the `something_horrible_is_true` condition.

There are also several more complex usage examples:

```
SELECT 
  case 
    when count(*) = 0 then raise_error('something horrible is true!')::int 
    else count(*) 
  end
FROM mytable
WHERE something_horrible_is_true
```

Returns count or rise exception when nothing found.

```
update mytable set
  mydatefield = 
    case 
      when mydatefield = current_date then raise_error('Can not update today''s rows')::date
      else '1812-10-10'::date
    end;
```

Prevents to update some rows (this is a somewhat contrived example but it shows yet another usage way)
... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with triggers? Postresql provides good suport for triggers especially using the pgsql laguange.

A trigger is a function (check) that is always run on an event: insert, update,delete. You can call the function before or after the event.

I believe once you know this concept, you can find an online tutorial to help you achieve your goal.

A general approach may look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_function() RETURN trigger AS
$$
DECLARE c integer;
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) into c FROM mytable WHERE something_horrible_is_true;
IF c>0 then  RAISE EXCEPTION 'cannot have a negative salary'; 
END IF; 
return new; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And afterwards you execute

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT
   ON table_name
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_function()
```

Both code sections are pqsql.